# Javascript object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Lets say I have a object like

```
> var products = {a:"b", c:"d", e:"f" ... it goes like this}
```

i want to put this object in array like this

```
> var arrList = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]
```

but i couldnt managed it'll be great if you guys help me thank you already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed like this:

```
var products = {a:"b", c:"d", e:"f"};

var arrList = [];
for(var key in products) { // iterates over products key (e.g: a,c,e)
   arrList.push([key, products[key]]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop and add it to the array

```
var result = []
for (var key in products) { result.push([key,products[key]]) }
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
var arrList = Object.keys(products).map(function(key) {
  return [key, products[key]];
});
```

Note, though, that [properties order in objects are not guaranteed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Comment: Above won't work if you're supporting older browsers (IE8 and lower):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

> Use [`for-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate through object

*for (variable in object) => variable is a property name*

Try this:

```js
var products = {
  a: "b",
  c: "d",
  e: "f"
};
var arr = [];
for (i in products) {
  arr.push([i, products[i]]);
}
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow

```
products = {a:"b",c:"d",e:"f"};
arrList = [];
for(i in products){
    arrList.push([i,products[i]]);
}
```